# Why is my OS-independent grub partition able to correctly boot into Ubuntu using an older kernel version but not with a newer one?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, kernel

I have a single hard drive with the following partition setup:
[image]

- sda1&2 are windows partitions
- sda4 is an extended partition
  containing the logical partitions sda5&6
- sda5 is the swap partition
  for ubuntu
- sda6 is the root ubuntu partition (version 20.04)
- sda3 is a partition
  containing just grub files, computer boots from here then chainloads windows or ubuntu bootloaders depending on what is selected in the grub menu

Basically, I have been trying to customise my grub menu using Grub Customizer, a gui for editing the grub config files and generating grub.cfg. Although successfully customising it with a different timeout duration and a background image, after choosing to boot to Ubuntu it eventually gets stuck showing the following "[ OK ]" log (I don't know how to call it):
[image]

Please note that I can still login at this point without gui by using ctrl+alt+f2.

I used the diff command to confirm that Grub Customizer generates the same grub.cfg as the grub-mkconfig command (almost equivalent to update-grub according to [this discussion](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/seeking-clarification-on-using-%27update-grub%27-and-or-%27grub-mkconfig%27-4175663337/)), so that isolated the problem to the grub configuration itself. After using kdiff3 and experimenting extensively, I discovered that if I manually altered the ubuntu menuentry in grub.cfg (the one on the grub partiton of course) in the following way, the problem would go away while keeping the desired customisations:

**faulty boot:**

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###

function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode



menuentry "Ubuntu" --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-c1cf0131-85a4-4147-b74c-38df34cd47cc' {
    recordfail
    savedefault
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  c1cf0131-85a4-4147-b74c-38df34cd47cc
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root c1cf0131-85a4-4147-b74c-38df34cd47cc
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic root=UUID=c1cf0131-85a4-4147-b74c-38df34cd47cc ro acpi_sleep=nonvs quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
```

**working boot:**

```
...
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic root=UUID=c1cf0131-85a4-4147-b74c-38df34cd47cc ro acpi_sleep=nonvs quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ###
```

(I simply changed vmlinuz-5.4.0-45-generic and initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic to vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic and initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic respectively)

I would like to:

1. know how using the 5.4.0-42 images instead of the 5.4.0-45 ones makes any difference
2. find the correct grub configuration options that work with the "45s", so I wouldn't have to edit grub.cfg manually every time I want to customise it.

**UPDATE 11:31 UTC+2, 9/9/20**: Just an hour ago I downloaded the new linux kernel (5.4.0-47) and tried using that to boot, but the same issue as 5.4.0-45 appeared. So I edited grub.cfg back to 5.4.0-42. So now I have 3 different kernels available to use: 5.4.0-{42,45,47}.
Just a thought but considering gnome desktop appears to start successfully according to the boot "[OK]" log (still don't know what its name is), isn't that the main suspect? That and the nvidia daemon failing closer to the top of the log.

**UPDATE 13:14 UTC+2 9/9/20**: Here is the result of `sudo systemctl status nvdia-persistenced.service` after a failed GUI boot:

```
● nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-09-09 11:54:44 EEST; 1min 43s ago
    Process: 876 ExecStart=/usr/bin/nvidia-persistenced --user nvidia-persistenced --no-persistence-mode --verbose (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    Process: 896 ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -rf /var/run/nvidia-persistenced (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[882]: Failed to query NVIDIA devices. Please ensure that the NVIDIA device files (/dev/nvidia*) exist, and that user 126 has read and write permissions for those files.
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[882]: PID file unlocked.
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[882]: PID file closed.
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[882]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[876]: nvidia-persistenced failed to initialize. Check syslog for more details.
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G nvidia-persistenced[882]: Shutdown (882)
Σεπ 09 11:54:42 george-Aspire-E5-571G systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
Σεπ 09 11:54:43 george-Aspire-E5-571G systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Σεπ 09 11:54:44 george-Aspire-E5-571G systemd[1]: nvidia-persistenced.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Σεπ 09 11:54:44 george-Aspire-E5-571G systemd[1]: Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
```

Comment: Bad idea directly editing your config file. Just edit your `/etc/default/grub` file and then run `sudo update-grub` then reboot.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Grub Customizer essentially runs update-grub, it's only a gui for editing the grub configuration files. I had to edit grub.cfg manually to avoid the problem. The way to boot correctly without editing grub.cfg manually would be the answer to this question.

Comment: Just setup grub to boot using the previous option. So if kernel A is default (first on list), but you boot with Kernel B, the next time you boot Kernel B will be automatically selected and you don't have to override the boot option. As far as what is broken in 5.4.0-45 for you I don't know but hopefully it is fixed in 5.4.0-46. Just make sure you don't run `sudo apt autoremove` and loose your `5.4.0-42` which does work.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks, that's a good idea. I'm still curious if there is anything I've done wrong or if it's natural that one kernel just doesn't work. Also I actually already have run autoremove and it does not delete 5.4.0-42. Both are kept for some reason.

Comment: There will always be times when a new kernel doesn't work for this person or that. This is why a previous version is kept. If you were to boot with #46 and run autoremove then it would keep 45 & 46 and nuke your 42. But if you run autoremove on 45 it will keep 42 & 45 (assuming 43 & 44 don't exist).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I see, I'll change the default to make sure nothing bad happens  then. Thanks again for the tips.

Comment: @gkats The `update-grub` command generates your config file based on what is in the /etc/default/grub file so you should not have to manually edit the config file unless you are an expert.

Comment: `/etc/default/grub` is the configuration file, `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is the "compiled" file for lack of a better word. As an aside if you are interested in customizing grub there is lots you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341871/finding-countdown-timer-in-grub-2-02-source-code

Comment: @darth_epoxy Yes, for the usual tweaks I would only need to edit /etc/default/grub. However, to change the order of the boot options or do various other tweaks, I have to either edit the files in /etc/grub.d/ before running update-grub (which requires some programming knowledge) or use Grub Customizer which handles that in a user-friendly way. Editing grub.cfg directly is not recommended because it will easily get replaced, but it literally cannot without me allowing it because it is in a totally different partition from the Ubuntu installation (it's invisible to it).

Comment: If then you manually type new details in your grub.cfg file under submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' for your additional kernels, are the enties identical except for the version numbers?

Comment: You almost never have to edit grub's scripts in /etc/grub.d. Grub Customizer does create new ones with proxy in the name. You can edit /etc/default/grub or create your own boot stanza in 40_custom, usually by copying from an existing grub.cfg file. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2076205&p=13787835#post13787835

Comment: @oldfred Oh sorry, I misunderstood their use then.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I'm not sure if I understand the question, but here are the differences between my normal Ubuntu entry (the one where I replaced "45" with with "42") and the "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-45-generic" one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2YhA.png

Comment: @darth_epoxy And also another one between "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-45-generic" and "Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic": https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbGV4.png. So yes, they are the same.

Comment: I think oldfred is onto it. However it is possible the image (img) is fubar and it would not be a waste of time remove and purge that kernel version and try again. I am currently experimenting with 5.7.1 and whenever I create a Frankenstein I just start again by falling back to 5.4.0-40 which is the most stable for my mac mini.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was running an older nvidia driver version that was not compatible with newer kernels. Removing the old nvidia drivers and installing the newest ones from ubuntu repos did the trick.

Assuming the nvidia driver was at fault, I performed a high-risk, high-reward maneuver by running this script (slightly modified version of one found [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/newly-installed-drivers-are-not-found-when-nvidia-smi-is-called/82686/7)) to uninstall all nvidia drivers and install the newest ones from ubuntu repos:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt remove --purge '^nvidia-.*' -y
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop -y
sudo apt --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" -y
sudo apt --purge remove "*nvidia*" -y
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo trash /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt autoremove -y

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

After installing the new nvidia drivers I did not modify grub.cfg to use the newest kernel (5.0.4-47) to see how the older kernel (5.0.4-42) would work. That resulted in the same error as described in the question. After that I switched the kernel version in grub.cfg to 5.0.4-47 and I could finally boot into gnome desktop correctly.

My conclusion is that after all, the problem was caused by incompatibility between the linux kernel and the nvidia graphics driver. If you have a similar problem, I suggest keeping both your linux kernel and the graphics drivers up to date, reinstalling nvidia drivers if you have to.